# How to write output to an external text file in addition to the standard output stream?

Tags: output-formatting, streams

How to write output to an external text file in addition to the standard output stream, i.e. a notebook for a session with FE and stdout for command-line session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expected this to work but it apparently only writes `Print` output:

```
AppendTo[
  $Output, 
  OpenWrite["out.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]
]
```

A workaround using `$PrePrint`:

```
output = OpenWrite["out.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm];

$PrePrint = (Write[output, #]; #) &;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `PutAppend[]` and not `OpenWrite[]`?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika how about `OpenAppend`?