# How to send output of Information[] command to a text file?

Tags: output

I am having little hard time sending output of `Information[]` command to a text file.

related question [How to write output to an external text file in addition to the standard output stream?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/how-to-write-output-to-an-external-text-file-in-addition-to-the-standard-output)

I'd like to find what is the correct way to do this. I tried the following 3 things, including what is in the above link, but nothing worked for me. I am using version 8.0.4 on windows 7.

```
s = OpenWrite["test.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm] (*without FormatType also error*)
$Post = Write[#, s] &
Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False]
Close[s]
$Post =.
```

second attempt

```
s = OpenWrite["test.txt"]
$Output = s
Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False]
Close[s]
```

Third attempt  (using the same solution given in the above link)

```
output = OpenWrite["out.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm];
$PrePrint = (Write[output, #]; #) &;
Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False]
```

I see the file out.txt gets created, but it is empty. Nothing is written to it. Even after I close Mathematica or the kernel, it is empty. I also get an error when I close it

```
Close[output]  (*Write::noopen: "Cannot open OutputStream["out.txt",19]"*)
```

Basically, I want to issue many commands in my notebook, in the form of `Information[...]` for many topics, and I want this otuput to go to a text file to process later.

What would be the right way to do this?

thanks,

**edit**

fyi, this is the final version. A small example, to show how it is now working: (this is part of a larger code I use to generate all the symbols in all packages in Mathematica). I was cleaning it to get ready to run it when V 9 is out.

```
Get["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]
SetOptions[CleanSlate, Verbose -> False];
addOnPackages = {"ANOVA", "Audio"};
output = OpenWrite["info.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity];
$Output = output;
$Urgent = output;

Do[{
   packageName = addOnPackages[[i]];
   Print["<", packageName];
   Get[packageName <> "`"];
   funs = Names[packageName <> "`*"];
   Information[#, LongForm -> False] & /@ funs;
   CleanSlate[Evaluate[packageName <> "`"]]
   }, {i, 1, Length[addOnPackages]}
  ];

Close[output];
```

Thanks for Todd and Mike help in this.

**update 12/1/2012**

FYI,

Based on what I learned from the replies here, I made this little function that allows one to capture the output from ? on command into a string.  (if you want ?? output, then just change the `LongForm->False` to `LongForm->True` (will update this function later to add this as an option to the call. But for now, just to give an idea)

```
help[fun_String] := Module[{s, file},
  SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
  file = OpenWrite["s.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity];
  Block[{$Urgent = file},
   Information[fun, LongForm -> False] ];
  Close[file];
  Import["s.txt"]
  ]
```

To use it

```
s = help["DSolve"];
```

and now `s` is a string of what would have gone to screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The output from `Information[]` gets sent to the `$Urgent` stream. Here is how you can capture it:

```
infoFile = OpenWrite["info.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity]

Block[{$Urgent = infoFile},
    Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False]
]

Close[infoFile]
```

Note that I used `PageWidth->Infinity`. This results in possibly (?) cleaner formatting in the file. It depends on how you want to process it.

Comment: Nice one! Where is this documented?

Comment: I don't think it is documented. Maybe somewhere. I tried `DownValues[Information]` and saw some tinkering with `$Urgent` in the definition, which tipped me off.

Comment: Even better than finding it in the docs. I've never used DownValues[] before...useful too, thank you.

Comment: @WalkingRandomly you could have a look at this post for more info on DownValues http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/66 or this one http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me

```
output = OpenWrite["C:\\Users\\Mike Croucher\\outtest3.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm];
$Output = output
Print["hello"]
Close[output];
```

I get the word 'hello' in outtest3.txt.  However, the following does not work

```
output = OpenWrite["C:\\Users\\Mike Croucher\\outtest4.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm];
$Output = output
Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False];
Close[output];
```

I get an empty file.  According to the documentation, the output from `Information[]` is a side effect but it seems to work in a different way to the side effect produced by `Print[]`.  After much mucking around with all kinds of settings I decided to cheat.

Create a simple text file called info.m using Notepad that contains

```
Information["DSolve", LongForm -> False];
```

Open up a Windows command prompt and pass this directly to the kernel, redirecting output to a text file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\math.exe" < info.m > output.txt
```

The text file contains

```
Mathematica 8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2011 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= DSolve[eqn, y, x] solves a differential equation for the function y
    , with independent variable x
     . DSolve[{eqn , eqn , …}, {y , y , …}, x]
                  1     2        1   2
       solves a list of differential equations. DSolve[eqn, y, {x , x , …}]
                                                                 1   2
        solves a partial differential equation. 

In[2]:=
```

It's very messy but at least it gets you some text you can post-process.  Is the above any use do you think?

Comment: You are welcome.  Life would be made much easier if Wolfram made Information produce normal output instead of a side effect.